# Click next button in first screen but detected next for in second screen

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a problem. I made a game with 2 menujema and playfield. When I hit the first menu button next to my senses as I pressed the button next to the other menus (buttons have the same coordinates). Now I wonder how this is possible?

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

public class AddAtributesPerson implements Screen {
    OrthographicCamera guiCam;
    SpriteBatch batcher;
    Rectangle firstPersonCharacter;
    Rectangle secondPersonCharacter;
    Rectangle thirdPersonCharacter;
    Rectangle forthPersonCharacter;
    Rectangle nextBounds;
    Rectangle backBounds;
    Vector3 touchPoint;
    boolean firstPersonCharacterBoolean, secondPersonCharacterBoolean,thirdPersonCharacterBoolean,
    forthPersonCharacterBoolean;
    Game game;


    public AddAtributesPerson(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    //  Gdx.app.getApplicationListener().setScreen(new Screen());
         Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
    //  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new Stage());
        guiCam = new OrthographicCamera(320, 480);
        guiCam.position.set(320 / 2, 480 / 2, 0);
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();


    }


    public void update() {
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {

        guiCam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));

        if (firstPersonCharacter.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {

                Assets.playSound(Assets.clickSound);

                firstPersonCharacterBoolean=true;
                return;
            }
        if (secondPersonCharacter.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
                Assets.playSound(Assets.clickSound);
                secondPersonCharacterBoolean=true;

                return;
            }
        if (thirdPersonCharacter.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
                Assets.playSound(Assets.clickSound);
                thirdPersonCharacterBoolean=true;

                return;
            }
        if (forthPersonCharacter.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
                Assets.playSound(Assets.clickSound);
                forthPersonCharacterBoolean=true;
                return;
            }


        if (nextBounds.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            Assets.playSound(Assets.clickSound);
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            return;
        }

        if (backBounds.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            Assets.playSound(Assets.clickSound);
            game.setScreen(new ChoosePerson(game));
            return;
        }           


    }
    }


    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update();
        draw();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you use fragment? In that case make the parent layout of the fragments context view clickable. This will fix your problem.

Comment: give me example i dont understand what i must use ?

Comment: and i dont use fragment..

Answer (score 0):

Because you are continous touching your screen.
You can fix that by adding a boolean variable to the second screen.

```
private boolean hasBeenTouchedUp=false;
```

And when you touch up make that value true.

And check something like

```
  if (hasBeenTouchedUp && Gdx.input.isTouched()) { ... }
```

To check when you touch up you need to use an Input Proccesor.
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx

A better solution would be to use justTouched instead of isTouched because justTouched is true only in the frame that you are touching your screen for the first time.
But this depends of your game :)

Other solution would be to check if the time elapsed after the new screen is on, maybe if 1 seconds passed check the input, but I don't think that this is the best ideea.